Possible problem with inbox message processing with FSharp.Core 8.0.300 version and beyond
My inbox message processor stop working when doing a PostAndReply. (F# MailboxProcessor)
I do I report a suspect problem with Fsharp.Core?  To whom?  Where?
It is running inside an Async function.
Version FSharp.Core 8.0.200 and back works.  Version 8.0.300 and beyond just sits at the following line waiting for response.  (Time out did not help.)
while not(model.State = Cancelled || model.State = Inactive) 
    && (msgProcessor.PostAndReply(fun replyChannel -> IsProcessingComplete replyChannel) 
        |> (fun (complete, msg) -> complete <> true) ) 
        && (continueWait) do
            do! Async.Sleep(sleepTime)


If I run this in the debugger in Visual Studio 2022, and pause it, the processing is just sitting on the msgProcessor.PostAndReply(fun replyChannel -> IsProcessingComplete replyChannel) portion of the logic.
I would suspect my logic, but this code was working until Fshare.Core 8.0.300.  I'll try to repeat this condition with some simple test when I have time.  I do I report a suspect problem with Fsharp.Core?  To whom?  Where?

It's dotnet/fsharp on GitHub, but you should definitely not report anything there until you are pretty darn sure you see a problem with the compiler. This is very very far from that, and is likely caused by trivial threading/concurrency issues. I wouldn't call myself an expert in that area, but there are plenty others here. So I recommend you edit this post to give us a reproducible example of the problem here first.
